# android: simple alarm clock

Tags: android, android-activity, alarm, alarmmanager

I'm writing simple alarm clock. It contains MainActivity with a ListView, WakeActivity with wake up message and a PlayerService that plays sound. I use the following code to set alarm clock:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, WakeupActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, a.getId(), i, 0);
    Calendar cal = getNextAlarm();
    if(cal!=null){
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        if(toast) showToast(cal);
    }
```

In android manifest WakeupActivity is defined as

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

In onCreate method I init close button. In onResume I start the PlayerService

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class.); startActivity(i);
```

When user click close button  I call `fnish();` and, at last, in onPause() I stop PlayerService. It works but there is one case I can't understand.

1. I set alarm and leave main activity on the top.
   WakeupActivity and PlayerService starts successfully. When I press close button I get back to MainActivity and everything's ok.
2. I set alarm and press home button. 
   WakeupActivity and PlayerService starts successfully. When I press close button then music stops and onDestroy() for WakeupActivity calls (like in 1 case)... Seems good but when I hold home button and choose my application then I get back to WakeupActivity and the music starts again!!! What the hell? I finish that activity! Why so? Please, help!

Comment: What is WakeupActivity doing? Is it possible that it's restarting the service?

Comment: WakeupActivity layout has TextView and a close button. So... it shows alarm message and start music... when close button is pressed then I call finish()

Comment: If you want help, cut the profanity.

Comment: Don't see any profanity... just anger! Trying to solve it for two weeks!!!

Comment: I'd guess this "What the hell?"

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui